# Filling a vector with objects which returns an empty vector

Tags: c++, oop, vector

I have a member function which fills a vector with objects:

```
std::vector<OptionData>& OptionData::createMeshExpiry(const double T_start, const double T_end, double T_increment)
{ // Ouput a vector filled with option data spread 
    std::vector<OptionData> optData;
    m_T = T_start; // intialize to first value 
    while(m_T <= T_end)
    {
        optData.push_back(*this); // push the current instance onto the vector 
        m_T += T_increment; // increment expiry time 
    }
    return optData; // return by reference to enable a cascading effect (if needed to change more than one var)
}
```

No matter how many times the while loop is run, the function always returns an empty vector. This implies that my while loop does nothing. How is this possible?

EDIT: After playing with the code for a while, I noticed that the issue was returning by reference. But why did returning by reference cause this issue?

Comment: Please enable your compiler warnings.

Comment: and then read them. The warnings are trying to help. Really.

Comment: Off-Topic: If you know how big your vector needs to be (which you effectively do) it is generally a good idea to initialize (or reserve) enough space in the vector up front. Otherwise you will get lots of reallocations.

Answer (score 4):

You are returning the reference of a local variable, that is the issue. Th scope of the local variable `optData` is only inside the function and as soon you reach the last brace of your function, system will call the destructor of it.

So correction needed to change it to return by value and NRVO will be taken care rest of it. So change your function as follows

```
std::vector<OptionData> OptionData::createMeshExpiry(const double T_start, const double T_end, double T_increment)
{
 //....
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but why does returning by reference cause the issue?

Comment: @Ryan C++ references (&) are always weak references. They go bad when the original object they point to goes out of scope or is deleted. You might consider returning a shared_ptr if you want a stronger referencing scheme. However, simply returning by value is fast anyway due to RVO.